# Spring RestTemplate message converter priority when posting

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

What is the most convenient way to influence the priority of the message converters Spring applies when POSTing with `RestTemplate`?

Use case: I want to ensure a given entity is POSTed as JSON rather than e.g. XML when I do `restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, Void.class)`.

**Default**

By default the entity is converted to XML because the `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` takes precedence over the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. The default list of converters for my app appears to be (Spring scans the classpath to see what's available):
[image]

**Option 1**

You can configure the message converters explicitly for a given `RestTemplate` instance like so `restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Lists.newArrayList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()))`. This is inconvenient if the instance is shared (as a Spring bean for example) as you might need converter X in one case and converter Y in a different one.

**Option 2**

You can set `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers explicitly in which case Spring will use a matching message converter. The downside is that you have to resort to `RestTemplate.exchange` instead of `RestTemplate.postForEntity` which means: extra code, less convenience.

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(entity, requestHeaders);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class);
```

**Option 3**

This might be what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spring javadoc (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) you can still use postForEntity,

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(java.lang.String url,
                                       @Nullable
                                       java.lang.Object request,
                                       java.lang.Class<T> responseType,
                                       java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> uriVariables)
                                throws RestClientException
....
```

The `request` parameter can be a `HttpEntity` in order to add additional HTTP headers to the request.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706610/how-to-set-default-messageconverter-to-json-with-jackson-dataformat-xml-added).

Basically, when you add the below-mentioned library, it adds  `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` before `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. As a result, Spring boot assumes every request accepts `application/XML`.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To avoid this behaviour, you might want to swap the two message converters.

Example:

```
  @Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
// move XML converter to the end of list
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
for (int i = 0; i < messageConverters.size() -1 ; i++) {
    if (messageConverters.get(i) instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
        Collections.swap(messageConverters, i,messageConverters.size() - 1);
    }
}

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

// add interceptors if necessary
restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(catalogInterceptior()));
return restTemplate;
```

}